# How to skip EOF while dealing with mutiple documents?

Tags: java, bytearrayoutputstream, bufferedoutputstream

My `ByteArrayOutputStream` contains data for multiple documents (Thus having more that 1 `EOF`). While I try to send the output using `BufferedOutputStream`, it only passes the data for the last document (probably because it overwrites all other docs but the last one).

Is there any way that I can skip all EOFs except the last one and pass it on to `BuffererdOutputStream`?

Java code below:

```
    private void outputBinaryTable(IRecordSet table, BufferedOutputStream output) throws ConnectorException, IOException
{
    IRecordMetaData fields = table.retrieveMetaData();
    int columnCount = fields.getColumnCount();  

    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    //Utils.write("Table " + tableName + " has " + columnCount + " columns.");          
    loc.errorT("Table Name " + table + " has " + columnCount + " columns.");


    if (table.first()){
        do  // For each row
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < columnCount; k++)
            {
                // Get the data as a byte array
                byte [] data = table.getBytes(k);

                outputStream.write(data);
                //Utils.write(new String(data));
                // Write the bytes to the output stream
                //output.write(data);
            }
        }
        while (table.next());

        byte [] combineData = outputStream.toByteArray();
        output.write(combineData);
    }

}
```

Comment: The EOF only exists at the end of the file, it&#39;s not possible to have more than one.

Comment: Most likely there is another reason why only the result from the last file is being retained.

Comment: Most probably you overwrite it when write multiple documents to single `ByteArrayOutputStream`.

Comment: Place some code that you tried.

Comment: I'm getting binary data from a different system(SAP ECC) and then trying to generate a PDF out of it. I've seen while printing outputStream (bytearrayoutputstream) that it has 3 EOF indicators which causes issue.

Comment: I cheated and read the documentation and apparently the column index for `getBytes(int)` starts at 1 not 0.